# Ejabberd STUN issue: unknown module mod_stun_disco failed to start

Tags: ejabberd, stun, turn

I'm trying to get video calls working with my ejabberd server, following [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ejabberd-xmpp-server-on-ubuntu).

My server runs the latest Debian.

Ejabberd fails to start after these changes and logs the following error:

```
@gen_mod:start_module:228 Failed to start unknown module mod_stun_disco: make sure there is no typo and mod_stun_disco.beam exists inside either /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ejabberd-18.12.1-2/ebin or /opt/ejabberd/.ejabberd-modules directory
@gen_mod:maybe_halt_ejabberd:311 ejabberd initialization was aborted because a module start failed.
```

How can I install mod_stun_disco?

Answer (score 0):

> My server runs the latest Debian.

And what version exactly is "the latest Debian" that you are running?

Also, what is the ejabberd version you have installed?

mod_stun_disco.erl was first included in ejabberd 20.04
https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/commit/69d1d62add92511acf58f5f71383ad64e4757464#diff-44e2dc2000d1cc7230e63af3a7f9618a7bb9afb64df1aec0cc91bf31c21c91bc

If you are running an older ejabberd release, obviously that module is not included.